# Can you connect (bridge) two GPIO pins over software?

Tags: pi-3, gpio, python

I am trying to bridge two GPIO pins on my RPI so that they will be physically connected. What I mean by this is that if I put current into one it will come out of the other pin depending on wether python program has connected them together. How would I achieve this through Python?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: You cannot "put current into" a GPIO pin; they are high impedance - the important issue is the voltage applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bridge GPIO in the way you suggest.  The Pi does not contain the hardware to act as a telephone exchange type switch.

The best you can do is monitor the state of one GPIO and mirror that state on another.

In Python terms:

```
while True:
   if GPIO1 == 1:
      GPIO2 = 1
   else:
      GPIO2 = 0

   time.sleep(0.1)
```